# how to continuously update a scrollpane from arraylist that has been toString'ed

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem that may be quite simple (although I have done my searches). I have an arraylist that I update at the click of a JButton. I've toString() this arraylist so that I can add it to a textarea.setText(xx.toString() so I can display on scrollpane. The issue is that each time add an eleement, the textarea displays the array and then the new updated array, meaning that the text gets double up each time. Is there another way around this? Thank you and know this is silly question

```
public  nameFrame()
{
    super("Name Generator");

    JPanel background = new JPanel();
    background.setLayout(new BoxLayout( background, BoxLayout.X_AXIS ) );
    name = new ArrayList<String>();

    getContentPane().add(background); 
    Box verticalBack = Box.createVerticalBox();
    Box horizbox1 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    Box horizboxmid = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    Box horizbox2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    Box verticalbox1 =Box.createVerticalBox();
    Box verticalbox2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
    getContentPane(); 

    background.add(verticalBack);
    verticalBack.add(horizbox1);
    horizbox1.add(verticalbox1);
    horizbox1.add(verticalbox2);
    verticalBack.add(horizboxmid);
    verticalBack.add(horizbox2);

    JButton maleName = new JButton("MALE");
    JButton femaleName = new JButton("FEMALE");
    JButton clearLog = new JButton("CLEAR LIST");
    JButton closeApp = new JButton("CLOSE");

    verticalbox1.add(maleName);
    verticalbox1.add(femaleName);
    verticalbox2.add(clearLog);
    verticalbox2.add(closeApp);

    final JScrollPane listName = new JScrollPane();
    listName.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    horizbox2.add(listName);
    final JTextArea nameDisplayList = new JTextArea();
    nameDisplayList.setSize(300, 300);
    listName.add(nameDisplayList);
    listName.setViewportView(nameDisplayList);
    nameDisplayList.setEditable(false); 
    nameDisplayList.setVisible(true);

    stringLog = Arrays.toString(name.toArray()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").replaceAll(", ","\n");
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : name)
    {
        sb.append(s);
        sb.append("\n");
    }

    nameDisplayList.setText(sb.toString());
    ///listName.repaint();
    ///listName.revalidate();


    nameDisplayList.setText(sb.toString());

    maleName.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            {

                try {
                    Scan = new Scanner(new File("MaleNames.txt"));
                    ArrayList<String> MaleFirstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while(Scan.hasNext())
                    {
                        MaleFirstNames.add(Scan.next());
                    }
                    Scan.close();

                    int Mindex = new Random().nextInt(MaleFirstNames.size());
                    firstName = MaleFirstNames.get(Mindex); 

                    Scan = new Scanner(new File("Surnames.txt"));
                    ArrayList<String> SurnameList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while(Scan.hasNext())
                    {
                        SurnameList.add(Scan.next());
                    }
                    Scan.close();

                    int Sindex = new Random().nextInt(SurnameList.size());
                    surName = SurnameList.get(Sindex);

                    fullName = String.format("%s\t%s%n", firstName, surName);

                    name.add(fullName);

                    //indexPoint++;

                    //System.out.println(name);

                    nameDisplayList.revalidate();
                    nameDisplayList.repaint();
                    for(String s : name)
                    {
                        sb.append(s);
                        sb.append("\n");
                    }
                    nameDisplayList.setText(sb.toString());

                    } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
            }
        }           
    });

    femaleName.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            {

                try {
                    Scan = new Scanner(new File("FemaleNames.txt"));
                    ArrayList<String> FemaleFirstNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while(Scan.hasNext())
                    {
                        FemaleFirstNames.add(Scan.next());
                    }
                    Scan.close();

                    int Findex = new Random().nextInt(FemaleFirstNames.size());
                    firstName = FemaleFirstNames.get(Findex);

                    Scan = new Scanner(new File("Surnames.txt"));
                    ArrayList<String> SurnameList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while(Scan.hasNext())
                    {
                        SurnameList.add(Scan.next());
                    }
                    Scan.close();

                    int Sindex = new Random().nextInt(SurnameList.size());
                    surName = SurnameList.get(Sindex);

                    fullName = String.format("%s\t%s%n", firstName, surName);

                    name.add(indexPoint, fullName);



                    } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }


    });

    clearLog.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {                   
            {
                    do
                    {

                        name.add(name.size(), " ");

                        indexPoint--;

                    }while(indexPoint != 0);
            }
        }


    });     



}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In your "actionPerformed" you need to either clean the StringBuilder content or use a new one. you are always appending to the same one so the content is added to the previous one.

Comment: +1 Nice spot.  Rather then making the `StringBuilder` final and reusing, simply create a new one each time...!

Comment: Got it! Thanks, sorry for late response my laptop shutoff from overheating lol :)